# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor

Tags: java, maven, guava

I have a project (`main`) that builds and executes fine.

I have another project (`envelope`), with a dependency on the `main` project, which builds as a fat jar (`jar-with-dependencies` using `maven assembly plugin`), which I then run from ALM (test management software)

When I run the fat jar, I'm getting this error:

> NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor

Google says this is caused by a conflict between versions of `com.google.guava` (different versions used at compile-time and at runtime?).

I've put a dependency to guava 28.1 at the very top of my `envelope` project's pom.xml, and put exclusions for guava under ALL other dependencies there. Yet I'm still getting this error at runtime!

How do I know why it does that? How do I prevent it from doing that? And how do I solve the error?

**EDIT**:

`mvn dependency:tree` shows only one dependency on guava.

`External libraries` show only one version of guava.

`Ctrl+N` shows two instances of the MoreExecutors class - one from the latest guava version, and one form a deep transient dependency on `org.apache.curator` artifact which contains the `shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors` class.

I tried excluding this dependency in my pom.xml, but then I get an error saying that the Curator failed to find the shaded.<..>.MoreExecutors class. So could this be the culprit, or is it something else?

**Setup**

```
-Java 11.0.3
-Groovy 2.5.8
-Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5
-IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1
-Maven 3.5
-Maven compiler plugin
-Maven build helper plugin
-Maven assembly plugin 3.8.1
```

Comment: Please show output for `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put your dependency inside Maven `dependency management` so as to manage version of artifacts used in transitive dependencies.

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- add your dependency here -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: What is the functional difference between declaring dependencies within a ``dependencyManagement`` blocks and without it?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html You can specify the versions of artifacts to be used when they are encountered in transitive dependencies or in dependencies where no version has been specified. In your case you have transitive dependencies using different versions of the Guava library. By using it you can specify which exact version to be used.

Comment: ``mvn dependency:tree`` shows only one dependency on guava.
"External libraries" show only one version of guava.
``Ctrl+N`` shows two instances of the ``MoreExecutors`` class - one from the latest guava version, and one form a deep transient dependency on ``org.apache.curator`` artifact which contains the ``shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors`` class.

Comment: I tried excluding this dependency in my pom.xml, but then I get an error saying that the Curator failed to find the ``shaded.<..>.MoreExecutors`` class.
So can this be the culprit, or is it something else?